# finding non-integer values in pandas series object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to find non-integer values like float,string in pandas series object?

Have a series object like this,

```
a=(1.2,3,4,5,6,2,8,5,9)
```

I tried `to_numeric`, but this is not helping to identify `float` values. Is there a way to check `integer` values?

Comment: You could do `a.apply(lambda x : isinstance(x, int))` or whatever this is but it will be slow for large data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` for checking non-integer values , if `type` of values is `string` and `integer`:

```
import pandas as pd

a=['a',3,4,5,6,2,8,5,9]

s = pd.Series(a)
print s
0    a
1    3
2    4
3    5
4    6
5    2
6    8
7    5
8    9
dtype: object

print [type(x) for x in s]
[<type 'str'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>]

print [type(x) == int for x in s]
[False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Or by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
print pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').notnull()
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
dtype: bool
```

If values are `int` and `float`, `Series` convert all values to `float`:

```
import pandas as pd

a=[1.2,3,4,5,6,2,8,5,9]

s = pd.Series(a)
print s
0    1.2
1    3.0
2    4.0
3    5.0
4    6.0
5    2.0
6    8.0
7    5.0
8    9.0
dtype: float64

print [type(x) for x in s]
[<type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>]
```

Comment: thanks for the response.i am reading dataframe with object as datatype . Because of that this column is showing as string in series. I also want to separate float types

Comment: If you read Series as string, you need convert it to numeric. And automatically is converted to `float`, if ther is at least one float value. Or am I missing something?

Comment: this is useful.And I also want to separate integer and float values into two different lists

Comment: I think separate integer and float is problem. Can you add Series with integer and float together? Becuse I try without success.

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution to separate ints and floats is to compare the floats with their rounded values:

```
import pandas as pd
a = (1.2,3,4,5,6,2,8,5,9)
df_floats = pd.to_numeric(a)
df_rounds = df_floats.round()
df_ints = df_rounds[df_rounds == df_floats].astype(int)
df_floats = df_floats[df_rounds != df_floats]
```